# Add delete button to table class

Tags: php, html

I wanna add a delete button to my table on each row, to be able to delete the ro .

This is how I have set up my table:

```
<table class="CustomClass" border="2" style= "background-color: #f9f9f9; color: #000000; margin: 0 auto;" >
      <thead style= "background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Tag</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo
                  "<tr>
                  <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['namec']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['datec']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['tagc']}</td>
                  </tr>\n";
                  
              }
              $result->free();
          }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have tried something like this, not doesn't looks like it is correct:

```
<td>
      <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this);">
    </td>
```

Any solutions here?

Comment: There's no "right way" to do it, that would work fine if you want to solve it in javascript, or you can use a form to solve through PHP with a page refresh. But if you want someone to help you, you are going to need to provide more information on why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

All right, in your thead add this above the other th tag

```
<th>Delete</>
```

and in your tbody add this above yout td tags:

```
<td><a href="/traitement.php?sup='.$yourindex->id.'"><i "crossiconwhaterveryoulike"></i></a> </td>
```

then in traitement.php add :

```
    if(isset($_GET['sup']))
{
    $id=$_GET['sup'];
    del_membreData($id);

    header("location:youinitialpage.php");
}
```

where del_membreData($id) is the function :

```
function del_membreData($idUser)
{
    $dbh=connexion();
    $sql= "DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE id=:id"; /*put the name of your table */
    $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute() or die (print_r($sth->errorInfo(), true));
    $sth->closeCursor();
}
```

I don't know every variables of yours but it might work.Of course you'll have to change some, just read the code carefully

Comment: I get error on the line `<td><a href="/traitement.php?sup='.$yourindex->id.'"><i "crossiconwhaterveryoulike"></i></a> </td>`. It says: `Syntax error, unpexpected '='`

Comment: in this line, try to replace doublequote " by simplequote ' and vice versa

Comment: Ok, so I did that and now the errors are gone, like this: `<td><a href='/traitement.php?sup='.$yourindex->id.><i 'crossiconwhaterveryoulike'></i></a> </td>`. No there is a columns named delete, but button or anything. And on my website, it says this: https://pastebin.com/enetaEGQ. Line 177 is the same line as the code I pasted in this comment.

Comment: Of course, you have to replace those variables by your own variables

Comment: ^ I also changed `yourtable` to `my_table` and changed `location:youinitialpage.php` to `location:index.php`. Still same error.

Comment: Now I tried changing to `<td><a href='/traitement.php?sup='.$row><i 'crossiconwhaterveryoulike'></i></a> </td>`, and on my page is says: `Notice: Array to string conversion in /storage/ssd3/554/14293554/public_html/index.php on line 177` ?